# Filterig initial data in Django ManyToMany field

Tags: python, django, modelform, manytomanyfield

I want to filter data in Django ManyToMany field.

The app creates Meetings that take place in some rooms which are located in some venues.

Many people can create Meetings, but a single person can just access to the venues and rooms that he created.

My models are (example):

```
class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    capacity = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('venue:room_detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

class Venue(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    rooms = models.ManyToManyField(Room)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('venue:venue_detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

class Meeting(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room)
```

I'm using Django generic views in my application.

**My question is, how can I filter only the specific rooms created by a user "User A" in the form of Meeting. "User A" cannot see rooms created by "User B"**

In the same way, how can I select just the rooms created in a specific venue without all the rooms?
I don't want to use JavaScript please.

Many thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the queryset from the form

```
#constructor from form
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    super(ObjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if user:
        self.fields['rooms'].queryset = Room.objects.filter(room__venue_creator=user)
```

You need to change `ObjectForm` with the name of your form

Something like that.

Comment: Thank you @Angel Cruijff for your quit response. I try your proposal and I've read many others tutos that did exactly as you did. Unfortunatly, it does not work with me. I'm afraid I'm loosing something. I try to trace my code by adding print('The user is : ', user) after the line "user = kwargs.pop('user', None)" and it prints "None" in the terminal. So, I cannot access to user. I try to import User by : from django.contrib.auth.models import User . But it does not help. Any clue to fix this please?

Comment: Where is the relationship between Rooms and the Creator @RufinHounkpe??? I don't see it.

Comment: No relation between Room and creator. It's Venue thas has a creator and there's a link between Room and Venue via rooms = models.ManyToManyField(Room) in Venue. If I can access to creator in Venue, then I can access to the rest of the data. In the  constructor for form, just after the 1st line, use wrote : user = kwargs.pop('user', None). I've added just after this line : print(user) and it prints None. I suppose that this user refers to the authenticated user.

Answer (score 1):

@angel

```
class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Venue(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    rooms = models.ManyToManyField(Room, through="VenueRooms")

class VenueRooms(models.Model):
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room)

class Meeting(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room)

class MeetingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Meeting
        fields = ('name', 'venue', 'room',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        print(user) # it prints None
        super(MeetingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

That is the models and the ModelForm for MeetinfForm where I'm trying to get access to the queryset of rooms and venur created by a specific user.
I suppose that user is refered to the autheticated user. It's like request.user; so by printing user un the shell, I should have the name of the authenticated user.